# Animation complete issue in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I use the complete from the animation and this is the result:http://jsfiddle.net/s5bhtq51/1/

```
$(".respect-row").mouseenter(function(){

            $(this).find("h2").stop(true,false).animate({
                'marginTop' : "-=80px"
            },{
                duration: 500,
                complete: function(){
                    $(".respect-row").stop().animate({ 
                        width: "320px" 
                    },{
                        complete: function(){
                            $(".respect-row .col-xs-12").find("p").fadeIn(500);
                            check_respect_or_quality = true;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        });
        $(".respect-row").mouseleave(function(){
            if (check_respect_or_quality === true){
                $(this).find("h2").stop(true, true).animate({
                    'marginTop' : "+=80px"
                },200);
                $(this).stop(true, false).animate({ width: "160px" });
                $(this).find("p").hide();
            }
        });
```

I have two function : mouseover and mouseleave. As you can see in the fiddle , it is working, but if i move the mouse pointer very fast on my div, it totally messed up the animation and i don't understan why. Can someone help me with this ? thx

Comment: Hey try this: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/s5bhtq51/3/  its not perfect but may give you some ideas.  Take note of the delay I added in the mouse leave.

Comment: thx, but it is not working, when i moved my mouse up and down, my header dissappear or it is moved at the top and after it disappears. :)

Comment: Maybe try and use .hover rather than mouse enter and leave look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186994/jquery-hover-animation-how-to-stop-properly-on-mouseout

Comment: if i use hover, it will trigger also on the child elements and i do not want that